# Artifactory 404 error on pulling package from remote

Tags: artifactory

We are running into a 404 error when pulling a specific package from the npm remote repository.  It seems to only happen with the @ngrx/effects@2.0.2.  We are able to install the 2.0.0 version and other scoped packages correctly.

- tested it with scoped and unscoped packages that we have never installed before and it works successfully.  Just this package seems to have a problem.

We are on version 5.1.0

Comment: What do you see in the request.log of Artifactory? 
Have you tried installing this scoped package directly from the NPM remote bypassing Artifactory and see if this workes?

Comment: Yes i can install it normally when pointing directly to npm.  That day we went to lunch came back and then he package installed normally from artifactory.  This keeps happening.  Whenever we want a new version of a specific package artifactory fails for several hours to cache it and then all of a sudden it's there.  when I was reading the release notes for version 5 it sounded like they were addressing this with a change to the nginx config.  But it still doesn't work.  Very frustrating.  Next time I will post the logs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the metadata retrieval cache periods. In order to avoid the latency associated with upstream connections, Artifactory will cache certain metadata from the remote site (NPMJS in this case). This can mean that the period has to pass before you can see anything new.

You can read more about the settings on Artifactory Wiki entry for [Advanced Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-CacheSettings). In your case, the relevant settings are `Metadata Retrieval Cache Period` and `Missed Retrieval Cache Period`. If you want to always receive the most up-to-date information, simply set those to zero (or a couple of minutes). This may slow down your builds a tad but it's a compromise between speed and completeness.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  The one thing I remember doing is clicking zap cache a lot during that time and it still not working.  And looking at the advanced settings doc zap cache should have worked.  I lowered the values and hopefully we don't run into this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

As administering my Artifactory install was not an option, I found an easy fix:

Remove the line containing the token to your artifactory server in ~/.npmrc.

This may be done with `npm logout`, however I didn't try that. In any case, the token being present resulted in 404 responses from the server.